Nav2 Custom Costmap plugin subscription
I am trying to write a costmap plugin for nav2 and i need to get a specific data from a topic but i couldnt create and spin the subscription inside the plugin. (I need coordinate points to create an obstacle at those points)

Would you be able to post the code you have to date and confirm the plugin is loaded? Might be able to give some directions from that.
There is also a tutorial here:
https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_navigator_plugin.html

Welcome to Robotics Tdelic, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it clearer.

Could you elaborate the issue further with any relevant logs?
As far as I know if you're running this with the layers of the global costmap, you should be able to add a subscription using node->create_subscription.
This is how it's done in the static_layer plugin for ROS 2 Humble. You can find it here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_costmap_2d%2Fplugins%2Fstatic_layer.cpp
